# Class which can be implemented by multiple backends and generic to code using the class

Tags: c++, oop, makefile, project-structure

Sorry for the really bad title. Essentially I have a program using a class I've made called "Cameras". The Cameras class tries to abstract away the underlying media framework I am using to capture images with some cameras. It can either use GStreamer or Nvidia's Libargus, and thus I have created two subclasses (GStreamerCameras and LibargusCameras) which implement a few abstract methods in Cameras. In my application to switch between the backends I have to change the declaration of the class between `GStreamerCameras cam;` and `LibargusCameras cam;` every time I want to make the switch. Could I somehow setup my project so that when I compile the object file containing Camera's implementation it chooses the backend there, that way in the code it can just say `Cameras cam;` and I never have to change anything or declare subclasses? What I really want is for the main application to not have to explicitly worry about what backend the Cameras class is using. What would be a good way to structure such a project's files, maybe to make it controllable via a makefile argument?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the part that irtual methods and abstract classes are (or interfaces), then read and learn the basic concepts. One possible implementation will then become apparent to you. Then, perhaps spend some time learning advanced design patterns (like the "pimpl" design pattern), to finalize this kind of an implementation. There is no magic button in C++ you can push to make it happen just like that, with minimal effort. You'll have to put in some elbow grease to implement this kind of a design. As far a "good way to structure", once you know what to do, that's up to you.

Comment: Hi Sam, I understand virtual classes are available, as I’ve mentioned above when saying that GStreamerCameras and LibargusCameras implement the abstract methods of Cameras. The caveat there is that they would have to be subclasses of Cameras, meaning the line where I instantiate them would need to be different (unless theres something I’m missing), that’s what I want to avoid. I’ll look into pimpl and go back to my old textbook. Thank you.

Comment: There is actually no alternative to thinking about what the common attributes of different types of camera are, and designing your classes, the relationships between classes, and the manner they are instantiated appropriately.   There is certainly no magic solution that will work for you, and save you from having to think about it.

Comment: Are you looking for [Abstract_factory_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)?